# Convexity of $x^p$ -- without calculus

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

At least in courses in Germany, you define $\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!$ much earlier than establishing basic calculus. Nevertheless, one can easily prove the convexity of $\exp$: For $t\in[0,1]$ and $x>y$ just estimate
$$
\exp(t(x-y))-1 =\sum_{n=1}^\infty t^n(x-y)^n/n! 
\le t\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x-y)^n/n! = t(\exp(x-y)-1),
$$
and it remains to multiply this inequality by $e^y$.

Is there an equally "elementary" proof for the convexity of $x^p=\exp(p\log(x))$
for $p>1$?

Comment: $x^p$ is not convex for all $p>1$, e.g., p=3. Are there conditions on the domain of $x$?

Comment: Of course, I meant $x>0$ because the definition $x^p=\exp(p\log(x))$ only makes sense for $x>0$.

Comment: I actually don't know if the proof of the binomial theorem for fractions uses calculus but if not, your proposed technique should be generalizable to $x^p$ as well.

Comment: Those proofs essentially prove variants of the geometric-arithmetic means inequality. You might try looking here for some ideas: http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Publications/Books/CSMC/CSMC_index.html

Comment: Unless $p$ is a rational number, I don't think you can avoid calculus completely.  The Weighted AM-GM Inequality with irrational exponents require some calculus.  At least, there is no algebraic way to define $x^p$ for irrational $p$.  You need some calculus for irrational $p$.

Comment: Even for rational $p$, I don't see a proof. E.g., for $p=3/2$ one needs to show that the convexity of $x\mapsto x^3$ is "stronger" than the concavity of $x\mapsto \sqrt x$.

Answer (score 3):

It can be shown that if $f(x), g(x)$ are positive, convex and increasing, then $f(x)g(x)$ also is. Noting that $f(x)=x$ is convex, we can inductively find $f(x)=x^p$ to be convex for all $p\in\mathbb{N}$.

Proof: Suppose $f,g$ are convex, $x,y,\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lambda\in[0,1]$. Then

$$f((1-\lambda)x+\lambda(y))g((1-\lambda)x+\lambda(y))\leq[(1-\lambda)f(x)+\lambda f(y)][(1-\lambda)g(x)+\lambda g(y)]$$

Upon expanding, we see this is:

$$(1-\lambda)^2f(x)g(x)+\lambda(1-\lambda)f(x)g(y)+\lambda(1-\lambda)f(y)g(x)+\lambda^2f(y)g(y)$$
$$=(1-\lambda)^2f(x)g(x)+\lambda(1-\lambda)f(x)g(x)+\lambda(1-\lambda)f(x)[g(y)-g(x)]+\lambda(1-\lambda)f(y)g(y)+\lambda(1-\lambda)f(y)[g(x)-g(y)]+\lambda^2f(y)g(y)$$
$$=(1-\lambda)f(x)g(x)-\lambda(1-\lambda)[f(x)-f(y)][g(x)-g(y)]+\lambda f(y)g(y)$$

The condition that they both be increasing gives that the middle term is negative, whence the whole expression is $\leq(1-\lambda)f(x)g(x)+\lambda f(y)g(y)$, as required.

Still working on something for the other $p$.

Comment: As noted by Benjamin Lindqvist the convexity for $p\in\mathbb N$ can also be obtained from the binomial theorem which, similarly as for $\exp$ gives $(1+tz)^p-1 \le t((1+z)^p - 1)$ for $z>0$. If one knows the binomial series (which I can only prove with more advanced analytical tools) this would also solve the general case $p>1$.